# Determine Circles

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry

Giving **`n`**(any amount) of points `(x,y)`. What's the minimum amount of circles required to cross every point given?

### Task

Your program will get `n` (you can have `n` as part of input or use EOF instead) points `(x,y)`.

The points might at same place => `(x1,y1) = (x2,y2)` **can happen**

`x` and `y` will be *integer* of range `-10000~10000`, while `n`, if you need it, will be *integer* too.

You should output an integer `A` which represent the minimum amount of circle needed to intersect all of the points. Those circle are not required to intersect each other.

### Explanation

For example:
1, 2 points will need 1 circle only to be sure that the points touch the circles boundary

but 3, 4 points may need 2 circles, or 1 (Determined by where the points are)

```
Basic test cases:
(10,10), (0,5), (0,0), (5,10) => 1 circle
(10,10), (5,5), (0,0), (5,10) => 2 circles
(1,1), (2,2), (5,3), (-1,5), (0,0) => 2
(0,0), (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5) => 3
```

**Line are NOT considered as a circle**

If there are 3 points `(0,0)` `(5,5)` `(10,10)`. Then the answer would be `2` since those 3 points forms a line if you try to force a circle out of it.

### Rules

- Input can be taken in any convenient format.
- Output can be in any convenient format as well. As long as it follow the input-reversed input order.
- Standard Loopholes are forbidden.

### Scoring

Golf your way to the shortest code!

Comment: @tsh the points maybe same (question edited to solve this problem)

Comment: This is a minimum set cover problem, where identifying each set involves calculating the circumcenters of triangles.

Comment: @Bubbler - although, obviously, two triangles could have the same circumcenter but different (and concentric) point-crossing circles, so just calculating the centres wouldn't be enough...

Comment: Will there be fewer than 3 points?

Comment: @att **yes**, there will be any amount of points.

Comment: [Python styled pseudocode for naive geometric algorithm](https://pastebin.com/C3i0xWw5)

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <sup><s>252</s>…</sup> 203 bytes

```hs
minimum.map g.permutations.nub
g[]=0
g(p:q:r)=1+g(snd$span(p#q$r!!0)r)
g _=1
(a#b)c d|t<-c!a?j(b!a)=t!!1/=0&&b!d?t?j(c!d)!!1==0
j[x,y]=[x,-y]
[x,y]?[z,t]=[x*z-y*t,x*t+y*z]
(!)=zipWith(-)
import Data.List
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDLbsIwEEX3/gobomITGxIeG4Rh0yX7LtKoch4EU@KYxEgk4tubOoG2QupmRnPnzJ2xD6L6TE@nVua6KA18FUZMdrIyYM/f21wqmV/ySS40zCY6LfOLEUYWqpqoSwSyIOQeyLBenVcl4b6b4UolTqWFwnp4dkqEPFISkMEP7gMshhGJYXIzaxYjsT3iCAnCDUL@lHsvLxFKtsaqMUqI1bi1PgZXWofcRlaHoC@2QUNNJ40bVo8NvY6NW4@bEGBEeCP1mzQHzAhg7Pk9bS6k4kkBIMSSFmTN@jOnfMRHZO1sstTspEpt@5QaqAupTMWDfuUN22gHylQkziAYuK503UE4CC3MWIcLVUEO@35SFhrOYLdHl9bE2T/MrNCd0GLfo75HKMQeXd5TXy07FfINtD/1iyz/R2YWoX4nzejs3pl3ifl//IN7jD7j8zu@oIufJR09h1/x/iSyqmWx1t8)

The relevant function is `minimum.map g.permutations.nub`, which takes a list of points as input (each point as a list `[x,y]`) and returns an integer as output.

This solution uses only integer arithmetic, and therefore does not suffer from accuracy problems stemming from floating point errors.

### How?

Coming soon, after I finish golfing this and convincing myself that the formulas are right.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 86 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to @att.

```
CircleThrough@#/.{_@{_.,_.}|_Circle:>1,_:>Min[#+Reverse@#&[#0/@Subsets[#][[2;;-2]]]]}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY1JC8IwEIXv/oqBQC@mS7pcKpaAZ8HtFkqoJbUBF2hTLzG/vcbainhwLjNv3vdmLoWqxaVQsiz6Cpb9SjblWRzq5tadaop8T3OquYe5Zx78baYZwTzN1vLK0Hwn7qJpBUUOQ4FP992xFaplKGcsXCzcMLdlnH7bSaHYppFXxRC4GVQWyXNwwKczAK01CTCQwGDQdkjGPuhkMAy2HHxzyX/Oqtc2xBCObvTqLvmOTfR04zcVjakYQ/z5aUz/BA)

Comment: [86 bytes](https://tio.run/##fY1JC8IwEIXv/oqBQC@mS7pcKpaAZ8HtFkqoJbUBF2hTLzG/vcbainhwLjNv3vdmLoWqxaVQsiz6Cpb9SjblWRzq5tadaop8T3OquYe5Zx78baYZwTzN1vLK0Hwn7qJpBUUOQ4FP992xFaplKGcsXCzcMLdlnH7bSaHYppFXxRC4GVQWyXNwwKczAK01CTCQwGDQdkjGPuhkMAy2HHxzyX/Oqtc2xBCObvTqLvmOTfR04zcVjakYQ/z5aUz/BA)